# Conditional definition of OVER() clause

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sum, window-functions

Assuming that I have a table `t` like below:

```
b    a    v
4    1    1
3    3    2
3    2    3
3    4    4
```

How can I use an analytic function with a conditional `OVER()` clause? In the example below, I'm selecting the cumulative sum of `v`. However, I want each row to cumulate the preceding values of `v` only if `b` (for each row that is being considered for the sum) is greater than `a` for the "current" row.

```
SELECT SUM(v) 
  OVER(ORDER BY v ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) c
FROM t
```

Applying the logic would give me the following result:

```
c
1
1
6
0
```

So my question is: is it possible to incorporate this logic in the definition of the `OVER()` clause? Or should I consider another approach?

**UPDATE**

Since the question seems to be misunderstood by many, I'll try to clarify a bit. The important thing here is to *cumulate* based on a comparison. The comparison is between the value of `a` in the *current* row (the row for which the cumulative sum is being calculated), and `b`, for each row that is being "considered" for the cumulation (preceding and current rows).

The example I provided happend to have a format that fitted the `if ... then sum else 0`-type solutions below. I've updated the example as well and hope that brings more light to the question.

Comment: "if `b` (for each row that is being considered for the sum) is greater than `a` for the "current" row" - why `1,1,6,0` ? 3 is not greater then 3, I would suppose it should be `1,0,6,0`.

Comment: Your right, my bad. `1, 0, 6, 0` is the correct output. I've updated the question.

Comment: Generally provided all `v > 0` there can not exist an output with two or more adjasent equal values under the condition.  Next value is either greater then previous one or zero.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What happens if the value of `b` in the first row is `4` instead of `3`? This solution will still produce `1, 0, 6, 0`. which is different from the cumulative sum under the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN b > a THEN v ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY v) c
```

**Edit**

From the comments, you seem to want an outer `case` expression instead:

```
CASE WHEN b > a THNZ SUM(v) OVER(ORER BY v) ELSE 0 END c
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think your answer will produce `1, 1, 4, 4` rather than `1, 1, 6, 0`.

Comment: @CHRD: yest, that what it will produce. I don't get the logic to generate `1, 1, 6, 0` though... Please explain step by step.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake there. It should be `1, 0, 6, 0`.

Comment: Thanks again! While this yields the expected result in the specific example, I'm looking for, as stated in the question, a way to get the cumulative sum (with my condition added). Imagine if we, for example, change the value for column `b` in the first row from `3` to `4`. The result with this solution will be the same, while the cumulative sum should be `1, 1, 6, 0`.

Comment: @CHRD: then you should create a question with sample data that properly demonstrates your use case, with proper sample data, desired results, and explanation. You can't have answerers iteratively guess and change the answers.

Comment: I thought I was clear enough about the cumulation in the original question, but it seems like most people are misunderstanding it. So I've made a new attempt to clarify things in an update. Feel free to have a look, and thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would just use a `case` expression in the `sum()`:

```
select sum(case when b > a then v end) over (order by a)
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  select *,
     sum(v) over (order by v) * case when a - min(b) over (order by v) < 0 then 1 else 0 end s
  from myTable
```

The [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1a6d2e44330af858b903b64341363afd)

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select if(b > a, sum(v) over(order by v), 0) 
from `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like my question is being misunderstood a lot. I've added an update and hope that can help clarify things. Cheers!